# MPI Haversine for distance calculation in C

Tags: c, mpi

I'm pretty new to MPI, so I tried to do [Haversine distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) calculating method in C, so far it seems work but I notice the result is incorrect, maybe something wrong with MPI method i used, here's my code :

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ROW 10                 /* number of rows in matrix */
#define COLUMN 2               /* number of columns in matrix */
#define R 6371                 /* averange radius of Earth */
#define MASTER 0               /* taskid of first task */
#define FROM_MASTER 1          /* setting a message type */
#define FROM_WORKER 2          /* setting a message type */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numtasks,                       /* number of tasks in partition */
        taskid,                         /* a task identifier */
        numworkers,                     /* number of worker tasks */
        source,                         /* task id of message source */
        dest,                           /* task id of message destination */
        mtype,                          /* message type */
        rows,                           /* rows of matrix A sent to each worker */
        averow, extra, offset,          /* used to determine rows sent to each worker */
        i, j, rc;                       /* misc */
    double  target[1][COLUMN],          /* longitude and latitude of target */
        dlat, dlon,                     /* longitude and latitude of destination */
        a, c, d,                        /* variable for calculation */
        destination[ROW][COLUMN],       /* matrix dest for listed destination */
        result[ROW];                    /* result in matrix */
    const char *name[ROW];                      /* name of destination */
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
    if (numtasks < 2) {
        printf("Memerlukan minimal dua MPI tasks. Membatalkan...\n");
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc);
        exit(1);
    }
    numworkers = numtasks - 1;


    /**************************** master task ************************************/
    if (taskid == MASTER)
    {
        printf("MPI dengan %d tasks.\n", numtasks);
        printf("Memulai...\n");

        target[0][0] = -6.9167;
        target[0][1] = 107.6000;

        destination[0][0] = -6.1745;
        destination[0][1] = 106.8227;
        name[0] = "Jakarta";
        destination[1][0] = -6.9167;
        destination[1][1] = 107.6000;
        name[1] = "Bandung";
        destination[2][0] = -7.8014;
        destination[2][1] = 110.3644;
        name[2] = "Jogja";
        destination[3][0] = -7.2653;
        destination[3][1] = 112.7425;
        name[3] = "Surabaya";
        destination[4][0] = -5.5500;
        destination[4][1] = 95.3167;
        name[4] = "Aceh";
        destination[5][0] = 3.5833;
        destination[5][1] = 98.6667;
        name[5] = "Medan";
        destination[6][0] = -5.1333;
        destination[6][1] = 119.4167;
        name[6] = "Makassar";
        destination[7][0] = -0.9500;
        destination[7][1] = 100.3531;
        name[7] = "Padang";
        destination[8][0] = -8.6500;
        destination[8][1] = 115.2167;
        name[8] = "Denpasar";
        destination[9][0] = -0.8667;
        destination[9][1] = 134.0833;
        name[9] = "Irian Jaya";

        /* Send matrix data to the worker tasks */
        averow = ROW / numworkers;
        extra = ROW%numworkers;
        offset = 0;
        mtype = FROM_MASTER;
        for (dest = 1; dest <= numworkers; dest++)
        {
            rows = (dest <= extra) ? averow + 1 : averow;
            MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&target[0][0], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&target[0][1], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&destination[offset][0], rows, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&destination[offset][1], rows, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            offset = offset + rows;
        }

        /* Receive results from worker tasks */
        mtype = FROM_WORKER;
        for (i = 1; i <= numworkers; i++)
        {
            source = i;
            MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&result[offset], rows, MPI_DOUBLE, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }

        /* Print results */
        printf("******************************************************\n");
        printf("Hasil:\n");
        for (i = 0; i<ROW; i++)
        {
            printf("Jarak ke %s: ", name[i]);
            printf("%f", result[i]);
            printf(" km\n");
        }
        printf("\n******************************************************\n");
        printf("Selesai.\n");
    }


    /**************************** worker task ************************************/
    if (taskid > MASTER)
    {
        mtype = FROM_MASTER;
        MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&target[0][0], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&target[0][1], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&destination[offset][0], rows, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&destination[offset][1], rows, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        for (j = offset; j<offset + rows; j++)
        {

            dlon = destination[j][1] - target[0][1];
            /* printf("dlon ke %i : %f \n", j, dlon); */
            dlat = destination[j][0] - target[0][0];
            /* printf("dlat ke %i : %f \n", j, dlat); */
            a = pow((sin(dlat / 2)), 2) + (cos(target[0][0]) * cos(destination[j][0]) * pow((sin(dlon / 2)), 2));
            /* printf("a ke %i : %f \n", j, a); */
            c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));
            /* printf("c ke %i : %f \n", j, c); */
            d = R * c;
            /* printf("d ke %i : %f \n", j, d); */
            result[j] = d;
        }
        mtype = FROM_WORKER;
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&result[offset], rows, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

This code should show distance from each place, since it's MPI, it should have exact same result, but the result actually change.
Also, some data sent to worker is equal to 0 which result in calculation error.

If you notice some mistake, please point it out.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want help finding a bug, you need to actually describe the problem, show us what about the output is wrong, describe what you expect, etc. You can safely assume that the rest of the world does not know what a Haversine distance is off of the top of our heads.

Comment: As a starting point though, you can look at `MPI_Bcast` and `MPI_Gather` do distributed and retrieve data from your workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from :

```
MPI_Send(&destination[offset][0], rows, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(&destination[offset][1], rows, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

if `rows==4` the first call to `MPI_Send()` will send `destination[offset][0],destination[offset][1],destination[offset+1][0],destination[offset+1][1]` since these elements correspond to the 1D array that will be sent. The second `MPI_Send` call sends `destination[offset][1],destination[offset+1][0],destination[offset+1][1],destination[offset+2][0]`. It means that `destination[offset+3][1]` is never sent !

It seems that you want to perform :

```
MPI_Send(&destination[offset][0], 2*rows, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

This operation will perform both lines at once : the second operation is to  be commented.
The receive operation should be changed as well :

```
MPI_Recv(&destination[offset][0],2*rows, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

Take a look at the [`MPI_Scatterv()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Scatterv.html) function : it does exactly what you want to do. Look at [`MPI_Bcast()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Bcast.html) and [`MPI_Gatherv()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Gatherv.html)